# Can I make an italic version of a font licensed under CC BY-ND if I only use it in a bitmap image and don't release the font file?

Tags: creative-commons

On a webcomic I'm working, I want to use a font distributed with a [CC BY-ND 2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.5/) license. That font in particular has regular and bold variations, but I also need the italic variation so I'm considering creating it based on the regular variation. To my understand an what I read on the [CC FAQ](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-reuse-an-excerpt-of-a-larger-work-that-is-licensed-with-the-noderivs-restriction), the license doesn't allow me to redistribute that italic variation by itself, but what I'm going to distribute is the webcomic that uses that variation rasterized as a bitmap image, not even the font file as could happen if I would distribute it in a .pdf, so it shouldn't be considered a derivative work.

I want to know if I'm right or I'm misunderstanding something.